# Different Insert response from mongodb nodejs native driver on OSX and Windows

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm getting different responses when inserting documents from Windows and OSX to an external MongoDB database.

Both systems are using mongodb driver v2.1.11 from https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

Inserts are working fine on both but the result I get back is quite different.

OSX: `{ result: { ok: 1, n: 1, ...other data}, ops: [the inserted records] }`

Win: `[the inserted records]`

Any idea why this is happening?

**Steps to reproduce:**

- nodejs: 5.7.0
- npm: 3.6.0
- mongodb (from npm): 2.1.11

Given a nodejs application, install v2.1.11 of the official MongoDB driver for nodejs:
`npm install --save mongodb@2.1.11`.

From your nodejs application, import mongo, create a mongo client and connect to a MongoDB instance and insert a document into a collection:

```
import mongo from 'mongodb';
const MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, (err, db) => { 
    db.collection('someCollection').insert({ foo: 'foo'}, (insErr, result) => {
        console.log(result); // Observe the result shape is different on Win/OSX
   });
});
```

Comment: So where's the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: My money is on the database versions being connected to are actually different. Extra credit says one is a MongoDB 2.4 instance.

Comment: The database is the same one. I'm just running my app from Windows and OSX but the DB is exactly the same one on MLab.

Comment: Again [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you want to make a claim then give me something I can reproduce. Simple code listing, server versions, and confirmation. Simple code to insert 10 items. It needs to be what you are doing and not what someone else comes up with, otherwise they might do something different.

Comment: I've added as much as I know how to at this point. It's basically "Insert a document from Win/OSX and notice the response is different". Not sure what more I can say.

Comment: I advise you to really check that server version. Here's some quick code `db.command({ "serverStatus": 1 },function(err,res) { console.log(res.version) })`. I keep saying this because I happen to know what you are describing appears to be a "legacy response", which would be exhibited by MongoDB 2.4. You should show your output and recheck the driver versions. But I cannot reproduce here. All OS types are producing the same output

Comment: I don't seem to have permission to run that command (the DB is on MLab) and I'm not sure how to change that (I'm already dbOwner). I've checked that both the OSX and the Windows app (same app) are pointing at the same MLab DB and they definitely are. I can see the mongod version is 3.0.7.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce with a server above MongoDB 2.4 is where the driver version is actually **not** in the 2.x series. And that too is to be expected. Check your `package.json` and `npm list` output. Check that you have not **"globally" installed** a 1.x series of the mongodb driver. That last seems likely. As stated it's either the server or the driver, and there really is no possible other reason for a "legacy" response format that you seem to be describing ( yet still have not included in the question ).

Comment: @BlakesSeven I'm experiencing the mentioned difference after a MongoDB 3 update...so I that makes it look like this is a v2 vs. v3 thing.  But you are calling something "legacy" when I don't see any documentation of the response format on mongodb's part.  Perhaps if you know something about this change you could document it as an answer here, because this question is all I could find on the topic...

Comment: Hey @HostileFork. I did find a solution to this issue. In my case there was a package.json burried deep in my solution that was referencing a different version of the MongoDB package. The old response is the one that contains immediate results from the DB. The newer response seems to be the one with DB results in an `ops` array. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a package.json buried deep in my application that contains a lower version of the MongoDB driver.

Removing this pacakge.json and ensuring that everything was kept in the top level package.json has solved the problem for me.

Comment: Good to confirm it was a versioning issue...but I still wonder where one would find documentation on the response formats as an official reference to link at near the relevant source.  Can't find much on Googling for "mongodb insert ops" with variations of "version 3" and "change" and "node" and "driver" except this question!